# Sort array after date

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have an array (python) containing 15k rows, it looks like this:

```
                   Date   Data1    Data2
0      2018-10-17 15:38     498     506
1      2018-10-18 15:44     494     509
2      2018-10-22 22:26     497     506
3      2018-10-16 10:35     499     507
4      2018-10-25 03:42     497     505
5      2018-10-22 21:20     489     513
6      2018-10-19 05:47     497     506
7      2018-10-17 13:16     494     509
8      2018-10-19 11:53     495     509
9      2018-10-21 16:21     497     505
.....
```

I want to re-arrange all rows in date/time order.
I have tried data.sort(), as I read someone suggested here, but didnt work.
How can this be achieved?

Comment: This is not an array. Is that a dataframe?

Comment: You are correct, my bad! Thank you for noticing.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data.Date, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
data.sort_values(by='Date')
```

Comment: This worked! Many thanks.

Comment: Update:
It removes the Data by doing this.. Any suggestions? Looks like this after: "4674 2018-10-15 10:54:00"

Comment: @Martik I have updated my code. Please reply if you are facing issues.

Comment: If the output looks like what you mentioned, then there should be an delimiter issue. Clean-up your input before reading it as a dataframe i.e. having a constant delimiter

Answer (score -1):

This worked:
sort_data = data.sort_values('Date')